# tablas relacionadas y cambiar datos en la vista laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, base-de-datos, laravel-blade

tengo tres tablas:

```
Schema::create('comp', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->string('direccion');
        $table->string('n_com');
        $table->string('comuna');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tipo', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->string('descripcion');
        $table->string('codigo');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

Schema::create('maquinas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('codigo');
        $table->foreign('codigo')->references('codigo')->on('tipo');
        $table->string('marca');
        $table->string('modelo');
        $table->string('chasis');
        $table->date('ano_fab');
        $table->integer('compañia')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('compañia')->references('id')->on('comp');
        $table->timestamps();


<?php
```

Modelo Matmayor

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Matmayor extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'mat_mayor';

     public function Comp () {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Compania','n_com'); // Le indicamos que se va relacionar con el atributo id
    }

     public function tipo () {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tipo','codigo'); // Le indicamos que se va relacionar con el atributo id
    }
}
```

Modelo Tipo

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tipo extends Model
{
    // asignamos la tabla 
    protected $table = 'tipo';


    // 
    public function Matmayor(){
   return $this->hasMany('App/Matmayor');
}



}
```

Modelo Compania

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Compania extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'comp';


    public function matmayor()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Matmayor');
}

}
```

Necesito que en compañía en la vista me de el nombre de la compañía (actualmente en la tabla máquinas guardo solo los `id` de compañia y el `id` de código.

en `codigo_id` necesito que en la vista me muestre el código (ej B) y no el `id`.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código de los dos modelos.

Comment: ¿cuál es el modelo que utiliza la tabla maquinas?

Comment: el modelo es class Matmayor extends Model

Answer (score 0):

Tus modelos no concuerdan con tu explicación ni con tus migraciones, por lo que veo estás planteando las relaciones al revés, pues según la migración, es MatMayor quien tiene una Compañia y tú lo explicas al revés.

Deberías tener algo así en el modelo Matmayor entonces según tu migración:

```
public function Comp()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Compania', 'compañia');
}
```

En el modelo Compania:

```
public function matmayor()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Matmayor', 'compañia');
}
```

Para obtener la información que deseas en el controlador y luego pasarlo a la vista, harías una consulta como esta, asumiendo que quieres partir del modelo de máquinas para obtener el nombre de la compañía:

```
$maquina = Matmayor::with('Comp')->get();
```

Lo que estamos haciendo es utilizar Eager Loading para cargar la relación.

y en la vista tendrías algo así:

```
Nombre compañía: {{ $maquina->Comp->nombre }}
```

Te sugiero que revises con mucho más detalle la documentación de Laravel y además el diseño de tu base de datos.

Comment: el matmayor tiene una compañia y una compañia tiene muchos material mayor. (maquinas)   el tema que tengo es que no logro que me tome  el id guardado en la tabla matmayor campo compañia y me cambie se numero por el nombre de la compañia que esta en la tabla compañia.  lo que la vista actualmente es tomar el id de matmayor y buscar el mismo id en la tabla compañia  por lo que no coinciden con la compañia real al que pertenece el mat mayor.

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6hpsDsi6lUfV2JKQ2ctMURiUDg/view?usp=sharing

si se fijan el id coincide con la compañia  lo que no es real a lo que esta guardado en la base de datos.  osea los dos primero registros corresponden a la B1 y RH1 los dos a primera compañia